# React-TypeScript: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm not sure why I got this error. So basically I'm dispatching the id from Product component to getProduct redux action. Not sure why it isnt working.

// The product component

```
    const Product: React.FC = () => {
       const { id } = useParams();
    
       const dispatch = useDispatch();
       useEffect(() => {
          dispatch(getProduct(id));
       }, [dispatch, id]);
    
       return (
          <section className="product">
             <div className="bd-container product-container"></div>
          </section>
       );
    };
export default Product;
```

// getProduct redux action

```
interface productId {
   id: string | undefined;
}
export const getProduct =
   (id: productId) => async (dispatch: Dispatch<Actions>) => {
      dispatch({
         type: actionTypes.GET_PRODUCT_LOADING,
      });

      try {
         const { data } = await axios.get(`${url}/api/products/${id}`);
         dispatch({
            type: actionTypes.GET_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
            payload: data,
         });
      } catch (error: any) {
         dispatch({
            type: actionTypes.GET_PRODUCT_FAIL,
            payload: error,
         });
      }
   };
```

Comment: You didn't mention the error message, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

Either an action object or action creator function could be passed to `dispatch()` function you got from `useDispatch()`. But here you are calling `getProduct` which is returning nothing, but dispatching actions.
Refer to more detail about `useDispatch()` hook here: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch

Redux has a dedicated article on how to deal with async logics here: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic